# How do I configure Kubernetes node labels when creating a cluster with kops?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kops

When creating a Kubernetes cluster on AWS with [kops](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops) version 1.6.2, how do I configure Kubernetes labels for nodes? My specific scenario is that I need to set the label `beta.kubernetes.io/fluentd-ds-ready` as true, because [otherwise Fluentd pods won't be scheduled](https://github.com/kubernetes/features/blob/master/release-1.6/release-notes-draft.md#fluentd).

My current kops command for creating a cluster looks as follows:

```
kops --state s3://example.com create cluster \
--zones eu-central-1a,eu-central-1b,eu-central-1c \
--master-zones eu-central-1a,eu-central-1b,eu-central-1c \
--topology private --networking flannel --master-size m4.large \
--node-size m4.large --node-count 2 --bastion --cloud aws \
--ssh-public-key id_rsa.pub --authorization RBAC --yes \
production.example.com
```

How do I also configure kops to set the label `beta.kubernetes.io/fluentd-ds-ready=true` on created Kubernetes nodes?

Answer (score 0):

From https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/issues/742

You can create a yaml file with the cluster definition and the labelling there. On an existing cluster you can then do a rolling update.

Comment: If you update your answer to include a YAML file corresponding to my command line switches in the question AND configuration for setting node labels as required I'll accept it! The point of my question is to suss out the exact configuration required to move forward.